# Verify the topology having as base $\mathscr{B}=\{ A_{a,b}\mid a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is coarser than the euclidean one

Tags: general-topology

Given $a ,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Let’s consider the subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined as

$A_{a,b}=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid  x >a,y>b\}$

and let $\mathscr{B}=\{ A_{a,b}\mid a,b  \in \mathbb{R}\}$

Verify it is a base of a topology $\tau$ over $\mathbb{R}^2$ coarser than the Euclidean one and that is not Hausdorff.

I already verified it is a base, but I am having trouble proving it is coarser, how do I go about it? I know I have to find some open set in the euclidean topology that is not an open set on this topology.
For the Haussdorff part I have done it grafically, but I am having trouble writing it down formally

to verify it is a basis, I did like this:
I verify the two conditions for a set to generate a topology

1. U=$\bigcup_{B \in \mathscr{B}}B = \mathbb{R}^2 $ I am unsure if I should just throw it there or I should prove it. To prove it:

$(\subseteq)$ Let $(x,y) \in U$, then there exists  $B_0=(a_0,+\infty)\times(b_0, +\infty) \in \mathscr{B},$ such that $(x,y) \in B_0$ . Since $B_0 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, then $(x,y) \in  \mathbb{R}^2$

$(\supseteq)$ Let $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, then there exists reals $a_0$ and $b_0$ such that $ x >a_0 $ and $y >b_0$ so $(x,y) \in (a_0,+\infty)\times(b_0,+\infty)=B_0 \subseteq \bigcup_{B \in \mathscr{B}}B= U$

2 The second condition : let $ B_1,B_2 \in \mathscr{B}$ and  $(x,y) \in B_1 \cap B_2 $   Then  $B_1=(a_1,+\infty)\times(b_1, +\infty)$ and $B_2=(a_2,+\infty)\times(b_2, +\infty)$ Now there exist $B_0=(max(a_1,a_2),+\infty)\times (max(b_1,b_2),+\infty)$ such that $(x,y)\in B_0 \subseteq B_1\cap B_2 $

since the two conditions hold, $\mathscr{B}$ is the base of a topology

Comment: Hint: your basis consists of only subsets which are unbounded in the usual Euclidean topology.

Comment: To prove the topology non-Hausdorff, you need to find points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ lacking disjoint neighbourhoods. Have you got an idea of what you might choose for these points?

Comment: "I know I have to find some open set in the euclidean topology that is not an open set on this topology." No, to show that $\tau$ is coarser than the Euclidean topology, you need to show that every open set in $\tau$ is open in the Euclidean topology. Then if *in addition* you can find a set which is open in the Euclidean topology but not in $\tau$, you will have shown that $\tau$ is *strictly* coarser than the Euclidean topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$A_{a,b}=(a,\infty)\times (b,\infty)$$
$$A_{a,b}\cap A_{a',b'}=A_{\max(a,a'), \max(b,b')}$$

This means that open subsets in the topology generated by $\mathscr{B}$ are not only unbounded, but also any two nonempty open subsets have nonempty intersection.

The equality $A_{a,b}=(a,\infty)\times (b,\infty)$ implies that the new topology is coarser then the Euclidean topology. The fact that open subsets have nonempty intersection implies that the topology is not Hausdorff. And a non-Hausdorff coarser topology obviously is strictly coarser since the Euclidean topology is Hausdorff.

Comment: To prove it is strictly coarser would it be sufficient to say that bounded euclidean open sets like (a,b) are not open sets of the new topology? I am just unsure if this is enough of a formal proof or I need to write down something. Also to say it is coarser in the first place: I take an element of the base and argue  that it is an open set of the euclidean topology without writing down anything?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO yes, boundedness argument is enough. The fact that $(a,\infty)\times (b,\infty)$ is open in the Euclidean topology follows from two observations: (1) intervals $(a,\infty)$ are open in $\mathbb{R}$ by the definition and (2) product of open sets is open.

Comment: Also I noticed the empty set can't be obtained as a result of the union of elements of the base, is this an error in the question?. I think they should give, shouldn't they?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO sure it can: the empty set is a union over empty collection.

Comment: May I ask you to give me some feedback on the proof of $\mathscr{B}$ being a basis I just added at the end of the question?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO I had to update my answer. The union property I wrote earlier is unfortunately false. I had to use a bit different argument.

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Also: what definition of basis you use?

Comment: $\mathscr{B}$ is a basis of a topology $(X,\tau)$ iff

1) $\bigcup_{B \in \mathscr{B}}B = X $ 

2) If $ B_1,B_2 \in \mathscr{B}$ and  $p\in B_1 \cap B_2 $ then there exist $B_0$ such that $p\in B_0 \subseteq B_1\cap B_2 $

Comment: And why was that union false ?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO I thought that the union of two elements of the form $A_{a,b}$ is of the same form. But it is not, e.g $A_{0,1}\cup A_{1,0}$ is not of the form $A_{a,b}$ which I incorrectly thought.

Comment: @J.C.VegaO and yes, your proof that $\mathscr{B}$ is a basis is correct.